# Index and DB memory measuring of HSQLDB with JDBC

Tags: memory, indexing, hsqldb

When working with the in memory version of HSQLDB with JDBC, is it possible to measure the size that the database (all tables + indexes) takes?
I would ideally want to access the sizes of the tables and indexes independently.

Is there a query suitable for this task or any other way that this can be measured?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate a rough estimate of memory use for each table based on the documentation: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/deployment-chapt.html#dec_table_mem_use

Use the `CARDINALITY` column of the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_TABLESTATS` view for the row count of each table.